# Crystal Report design file to BI publisher template

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, bi-publisher

I am currently working on the conversion of Crystal Report to BI publisher report.

I am wondering if there's a way to convert the crystal .rpt design file to word .rtf template directly?

Comment: RTF is a standard export option from Crystal.  But if you are looking for an RPT to RTF conversion utility without opening Crystal, I've never heard of one.

Comment: @EvilBob22 what I want is to convert the rpt **design** file to BI XMLP template, such as the layout, the fields etc, not the output report, is that possible pls?

Comment: That's what I was afraid you were looking for.  I don't know of a way to do that, hopefully someone else does.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a tool to convert the crystals to BI publisher. we would have to build it from scratch by looking at the crystal. That is what I have been doing when they say convert crystals to BI publisher.